# Generating function of a Fibonacci series but with certain variation.

Tags: generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

Let $f_n$ denote the $nth$ Fibonacci number then what is the generating function for the sequence$f_0,0,f_2,0,f_4,0,...$ $$\text{Attempt}$$Its known that the sequence has following two properties.\begin{align}
\smash[b]{\sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i-1}}&=F_1+F_3+F_5+\cdots+F_{2n-1}\\
&=F_{2n}\\
\end{align}
$$\begin{align}
\smash[b]{\sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i}}&=F_2+F_4+F_6+\cdots+F_{2n}\\
&=F_{2n+1}-1\\
\end{align}$$ I will intentionally not start from $0$.
$$B(x)=F_2x^1+0+F_4x^2+..=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}F_{2k}x^k \implies B(1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k}F_{2i-1}$$.But i dont see how to proceed from here. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. If $f$ is the generating function of any sequence $f_0,f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\dots$ then 
$$\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}=f_0+f_2x^2+f_4x^4+\dots.$$

Comment: oh! I am feeling so silly now!